# How do I get rid of mold from the bottom of a bath mat (where the suction cups are)?

Tags: bathroom, cleaning, mold

We have a bathmat that we use to line the tub when we bathe our daughter. After the bath, we remove the mat and suction it to the shower wall (which is some sort of frosted glass)

I've noticed black mold growing on the suction cups.

I tried to use vinegar...sprayed it and tried to wipe off the mold. I tried a little bleach too.

Nothing seems to remove it.

Is there something else I should try?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My experience is that the black growth actually gets right into the bath mat material and cannot be easily removed. I suggest that you replace the mat and then use an alternate procedure when stowing the mat after use.

After use always rinse it off well so no bath scum and other things are left on it. Then hang it up over a towel bar, suction cut side up, so that it can fully dry after each use. When you suction cup the wet mat to the wall you are leaving it there as a perfect breeding ground for mold and mildew growth to occur.

Answer (score 5):

If you let is sit in a bleach solution the mold will eventually fall off (with maybe a thorough scrubbing - sos pad).  You might want to throw it away.  It got the mold because you suctioned it to the wall leaving water trapped inside the cups - a breeding ground in a humid bathroom.

Answer (score 3):

Run it through the washing machine on hot with some towels, detergent, and bleach. This is how I clean my shower curtain liner.

Comment: +1 for the practical solution.  I did suggest the guy solution of letting it sit in the basement/garage in bleach.  I like the bleach smell though!

Comment: Hi Lisa. Do you do this as a maintenance technique to prevent mold growth or is it effective at getting rid of all the mold after it has settled in? I feel like the mold is in the rubber because I can't scrub it off.

Comment: It won't prevent mold growth, but it will remove it. For mold prevention, Michael Karas' suggestions above will work.

Answer (score 1):

I went a different route. I bought a peel and stick hotel bathtub mat. It was guaranteed not to mold or turn slimy. And it hasnt in four years. I love it. Hotels cant afford a slip and fall or to have mold growing so they really do have the best mat. It has a strong adhesive that keeps it glued to the bottom. I found mine at Safetybathmat.com. I will never go back to a suction cup bathmat. Really it is great.

Answer (score -1):

There is nothing you can do once black mold grows, I've tried everything. Just throw it away and buy another and do this. When you get your new one after using the tub remove the rubber mat and roll it in a towel to dry it. When thoroughly dry no mold will grow. Sorry to say there is no easy way to keep your mat mold free other that to keep it completely dry when not in use.

Comment: -1 This post doesn't add anything not covered in other answers. It would be more appropriate to [vote up](http://diy.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) those answers than posting a duplicate answer.